# It's posisble to pass query conditions to HIbernate like is done with CakePHP?

Tags: java, hibernate, cakephp

In CakePHP, I can query the database passing the `WHERE` and `ORDER` conditions in an associative array like in the example:

```
$cities= $this->City->find('all', 
    array('conditions' => array('state_id' => $stateId), 
    'order'  => 'City.name')
);
```

Now I'm starting to work with Java Hibernate and want to know if there is something similar, maybe using a HashMap or another collection.

I didn't find anything similar in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a query using a `Map`.

For example given this query:

```
final Query query = session.createQuery("from MyThing mt where mt.something = :value1 and mt.somethingElse > :value2");
```

You can pass the parameters `value1` and `value2` in using a the [`setProperties`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setProperties%28java.util.Map%29) method:

```
final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("value1", 10);
properties.put("value2", 25);

query.setProperties(properties);
```

Values from the `Map` will be bound by key.

You can also use a java `Object` with [the other `setProperties`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setProperties%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Here `value1` will be bound to the result of `getValue1()` called on the passed in bean.

Comment: In this way I need to declare the parameters in the query previously. There is a way where I dont' need to declare the conditions in the HQL, but only passing the Map?

Comment: Not really, no. The criteria API allows you to build queries in an OO way with a fluent interface, maybe that's more what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know of is the [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html). Due to the nature of Java, it's a bit more cumbersome to use, though.